# Trying to implement stormpath login api java webapp using maven from github

Tags: maven, github, stormpath

I am implementing login api from stormpath am not sure how to Add the Stormpath Java Servlet Plugin from github to my application.

I need to know how to download Stormpath Java SDK .jars from github and add them to my java web application using Maven . I am using Netbeans IDE.

I m following instruction from https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/.

https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java is the github link for the sdk

GitHub lets me download a zip file. I need to know how to add it to local maven repo?

I am getting stuck at adding the servlet plugin part of the instruction as i don't know how to do it> Are they asking me to add it to local maven repo?

Please tell me how to do this on my java web app. ie step by step instruction in adding the servlet pluggin from github .

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [current version of those instructions](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/quickstart.html#add-the-stormpath-java-servlet-plugin), you should be able to get going by just including a dependency on the `stormpath-servlet-plugin`.

Since you are using Maven, you can do this by including

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormpath-servlet-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

in the `pom.xml` of your project.

You shouldn't need to interact with the `stormpath-servlet-plugin` GitHub project unless you are planning to contribute to that project itself.